# Getting JSONObject

Tags: json, android-studio

I am making a weather forecast app by searching cities in the circle. Using API api.openweathermap.org.
When I retrieve the 'list' array and run my application. It shows "No value for list". Can somebody help me how to retrieve all the cities in the circle that I search for. My API is http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?lat=33.5&lon=22.5&cnt=5&appid=83e20e46727fbf09e4dc1f76a2dcce62

```
 try {
            content2 = weather.execute("https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?lat=" +
                    lat + "&lon=" + lon + "&cnt=" + countCountry + "&appid=83e20e46727fbf09e4dc1f76a2dcce62").get();
           // for (int i = 0; i < countCountry.length(); i++) {
            Log.i("contentData",content2);
  //JSON
            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content2);
            String cityList=jsonObject.getString("list");
            JSONArray cityArray=new JSONArray(cityList);

            for (int i = 0; i < countCountry.length(); i++) {

            String cityName = jsonObject.getString("name");
             //   String cityName = jsonObject.getString("count");
            String weatherData = jsonObject.getString("weather");
            String mainTemperature = jsonObject.getString("main");
            double visibility;

                    JSONArray array = new JSONArray(weatherData);

                    String main = "";
                    String description = "";
                    String temperature = "";

                    for (int j = 0; j < array.length(); j++) {
                        JSONObject weatherPart = array.getJSONObject(j);
                        main = weatherPart.getString("main");
                        description = weatherPart.getString("description");
                    }

                    //wind cloud
                    JSONObject jsonObjectWind = jsonObject.getJSONObject("wind");
                    String wind = jsonObjectWind.getString("speed");
                    JSONObject jsonObjectCloud = jsonObject.getJSONObject("clouds");
                    String cloud = jsonObjectCloud.getString("all");

                    JSONObject jsonObjectSys = jsonObject.getJSONObject("sys");
                    String countryName = jsonObjectSys.getString("country");


                    JSONObject mainPart = new JSONObject(mainTemperature);
                    temperature = mainPart.getString("temp");

                    visibility = Double.parseDouble(jsonObject.getString("visibility"));
                    //By default visibility is in meter
                    int visibiltyInKilometer = (int) visibility / 1000;

                    Log.i("Temperature", temperature);

            /*Log.i("main",main);
            Log.i("description",description);*/

                    String resultText =
                            "City :                 " + cityName + "," + countryName +
                                    "\nMain :                     " + main +
                                    "\nDescription :        " + description +
                                    "\nTemperature :        " + temperature + "*C" +
                                    "\nVisibility :              " + visibiltyInKilometer + " KM" +
                                    "\nWind:        " + wind +
                                    "\nCloud:       " + cloud;

                    result.setText(resultText);
                    //Now we will show this result on screen
               }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The `list` mentioned in the code is not a string. There are few other places where string and array are interchangeably used.

Below I have added a gist of code on how to read the given JSON data.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(content2);
JSONArray list = jsonObject.getJSONArray("list");

for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++) {
  JSONObject listObject = list.getJSONObject(i);
  String name = listObject.getString("name");
  
  JSONObject listObjectCoord = list.getJSONObject("coord");
  String lat = listObjectCoord.getString("lat");
  String lon = listObjectCoord.getString("lon");
  
  JSONObject listObjectMain = list.getJSONObject("main");
  String temp = listObjectMain.getString("temp");
  String humidity = listObjectMain.getString("humidity");
  
  JSONArray listArrayWeather = list.getJSONArrayt("weather");
  JSONObject listArrayWeatherObject = list.getJSONObject(0);
  String main = listArrayWeatherObject.getString("main");
  String description = listArrayWeatherObject.getString("description");
}
```

Since it is just a gist, I have not added the code to retrieve all the data you require, but I'm sure you will understand and write code on your own for the required values.

You may refer to [this](https://www.journaldev.com/10642/android-jsonobject-json-parsing) to better understand how to read JSON data.